# calling http url is working but Https is not working

Tags: javascript

I created self-signed certificate and bind with site for using https protocol and also its working fine in IIS but problem is that whenever I access contained webservice url(https://webservice/webmethod) into jquery ajax call for posting data and its cant work.

```
enter code here
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function btncallWebService() {
        $.ajax({
            //url is just for understanding 
            url: 'https://localhost/.../EditFormServices.asmx/WebSvcSave',
            data: { sData:"bbbb" },
            method: 'post',
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function (respo) {
                alert("success"+respo.d);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("error");
            }

        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

Your url is wrong

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function btncallWebService() {
        $.ajax({
            //url is just for understanding 
            url: '/WebSvcSave',
            data: { sData:"bbbb" },   
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function (respo) {
                alert("success"+respo.d);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("error");
            }

        });
    }
</script>
```

Hope it helps;)